# Using an equation in intercepts, write an implicit equation of the plane

Tags: coordinate-systems, plane-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

Using an equation in intercepts, write an implicit equation of the plane which intersects the Cartesian coordinate axes X, Y and Z at the three points with coordinates P1=(2, 0, 0), P2=(0, 4, 0) and P3=(0, 0, 6), respectively.

I am having a hard time visualizing this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $6x+3y+2z=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known formula, similar to the formula for the equation of a line in a plane, given its intercepts:

If the $x$-intercept of the plane is $(a,0,0)$, its $y$-intercept $(0,b,0)$ and its $z$-intercept $(0,0,c)$ $(a,b, c\ne 0)$, the equation of the plane is
$$\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc=1.$$

Comment: thank you so much!!!